# calculate length of first name and lastname in Mule

Tags: mule4

Suppose client application sends firstName, lastName as a query parameter to your api.
Requirement:

1. In a separate flow, calculate the length of firstName, lastName.
2. Return the length of the firstName and lastName to your api consumer.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to convert your post into a valid question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is how to obtain the length of the query parameters and transform that information in a response for your API a simple transformation with a DataWeave script like this will suffice:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  "firstNameSize" sizeOf(attributes.queryParams.firstName),
  "lastNameSize": sizeOf(attributes.queryParams.lastName)
}
```